# ggplotly and shiny - Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

**Hello,
I am new to coding in R and using a Tidy Tuesday dataset to build a shiny app (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-04-07/tdf_winners.csv).**

**I am getting an error reading, "Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector" and have narrowed down the error to be with the "nationality" column. Here are the columns of my dataset (I created the year_raw column using lubridate from the start_date column):**

```
[1] "edition" "start_date" "winner_name" "winner_team" "distance" "time_overall"
[7] "time_margin" "stage_wins" "stages_led" "height" "weight" "age"
[13] "born" "died" "full_name" "nickname" "birth_town" "birth_country" 
[19] "nationality" "year_raw"
```

**Here's the sever.R code chunk where I think the error is:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    ds <- tdf_winners_years %>%
        filter(year_raw >= input$startyear, year_raw <= input$endyear, nationality %in% input$nationalities)
    
    ggplot.plot <- ggplot(ds, aes(x = year_raw, y = time_overall, color = nationality)) +
        geom_line(size = 0.5)
    
    ggplotly(ggplot.plot)
```

**Here's the corresponding ui.R code chunk:**

```
numericInput(inputId = "startyear", label = "Enter starting year",
    value = 1960, min = 1903, max = 2019, step = 1),
numericInput(inputId = "endyear", label = "Enter ending year",
    value = 1970, min = 1903, max = 2019, step = 1),
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "nationalities", label = "Nationalities to display",
    sort(unique(nationality_unique)),
    selected = c('France', 'Luxembourg'))
```

**When I type each part of the filter function separately, I find the error is with:**

```
filter(nationality %in% input$nationalities)
```

Comment: You can put `browser()` in your `renderPlotly({})` function and inspect what you have for  `input$nationalities`.

Comment: Do you get the error every time or only when no nationality is selected (then `input$nationalities` is `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `req()`.  Try this

```
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$nationalities)
    ds <- tdf %>%
      filter(nationality %in% input$nationalities)
      #filter(year_raw >= input$startyear, year_raw <= input$endyear, nationality %in% input$nationalities)
    
    ggplot.plot <- ggplot(ds, aes(x = year_raw, y = time_overall, color = nationality)) +
      geom_line(size = 0.5)
    
    ggplotly(ggplot.plot)
  })
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! That worked! On the ui.R side I have: `checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "nationalities", label = "Nationalities to display",
                               sort(unique(nationality_unique)),
                               selected = c("France", "Italy"))` but the two nationalities listed are not selected upon running the app. Thoughts?

Comment: Try `selected = nationality_unique[1:2]`.  It works.  There is some space before the names; hence, it didn't work.

Comment: For the two countries in your comment, it will be `nationality_unique[c(1,4)]`